# Is it possible to make a java program executable by simply calling its name (without "java ..")?

Tags: java, jar

I would like to be able to call a java programm like a real unix tool, e.g. with

```
user/home> myapp [args]
```

instead of

```
user/home> java -jar path/to/myapp.jar [args]
```

Is that possible (on Linux and/or Windows)?

Comment: in linux, you can make an alias for this command, in windows may be you can write a batch program that will in turn call the command

Comment: Can't you associate `.jar` files in Windows to Java, so that it automatically calls Java to execute?

Comment: @redflar3 That would indeed be a usable workaround, but is there any "official" way of doing this, with Maven maybe?

Comment: i don't think there is any official way of doing this. for running a java application, you need to call the JVM (java executable). You can delegate this to an alias or a script or even another application, but ultimately all those have to call `java -jar name.jar [args]`..

Comment: Why don't you just write a shell script (or .bat file)? That is the common way to simplify the startup of programs, e.g. setting up PATH, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem

- By making alias
- By writing CLI script file .sh (unix) or .bat (windows) file which essentially wraps the run command. e.g [Apache tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) follows this approach
- By packaging to the platform exectuable.  e.g. [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) follows this approach.